# Stop slideToggle div from scrolling browser down when expanded by hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div of text that shows and hides on hover using SlideToggle. The problem is when the div is closer to the top of the browser and you hover over it to expand it, The div scrolls the browser down instead of expanding out of view port.

Here is a link to the [example](http://rasouli.starmendev.com/). Its the 4 columns of images under the "We've got your back" section. The last 3 columns work properly, only the first column is behaving as previously stated.

```
$(' .expandColumn').mouseenter(function() {    
     if ($(window).width() > 768) {        
      $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.showWrapper').stop().slideToggle();     
        $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.bg').addClass('bgOver');
        $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.cross').children('.a').addClass('blackBG');
        $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.cross').children('.b').addClass('blackBG');
       $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.readmore').stop().fadeIn();                       
     }        

});

 $(' .expandColumn').mouseleave(function() {         
      if ($(window).width() > 768) {        
         $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.showWrapper').stop().slideToggle();
         $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.bg').removeClass('bgOver');
         $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.cross').children('.a').removeClass('blackBG');
         $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.cross').children('.b').removeClass('blackBG');
         $(this).children('.copyWrapper').children('.roundButton').children('.readmore').stop().fadeOut();              
      }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to include the relevant parts of your code

Comment: I updated the code. Thank you.